# OpenBSD 5.2 and Intel GMA X4500: How to get the X Window System to work

Tags: xorg, openbsd, intel-gma

I've just installed OpenBSD 5.2 on my desktop computer and I can't get the X Window System to work. My graphics card is Intel GMA X4500. When I run `startx`, my system freezes and no keyboard interaction is possible. So I perform a hard reset. Moreover, `X -configure` gives me segmentation faults and the X configuration is aborted. Has anyone managed to get Intel GMA X4500 and X working perfectly?

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to [-current](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/current.html) or wait [the next release (May 1)](http://www.openbsd.org/53.html). Probably your issue is fixed, the support for Intel graphics cards have been greatly enhanced in -current.